# How do I dynamically load a Jenkins pipeline library from Perforce?

Tags: jenkins, perforce, jenkins-groovy

I want to *dynamically* load a library for my Jenkins pipeline. The [docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#retrieval-method) say to do this:

```java
library identifier: 'custom-lib@master', retriever: modernSCM(
  [$class: 'GitSCMSource',
   remote: 'git@git.mycorp.com:my-jenkins-utils.git',
   credentialsId: 'my-private-key'])
```

But I use Perforce instead of Git, and I don't know how to translate that code accordingly. Jenkins' Pipeline Syntax tool spits out a snippet that doesn't look at all similar (and no, putting this in doesn't work).

```java
p4 credential: 'p4creds', workspace: streamSpec(charset: 'none', format: '', pinHost: false, streamName: '//stream')
```

I think what needs to happen is that I need to convert that `p4()` incantation to something that looks more like `modernSCM([ $class: 'PerforceSCM' ])`. However, I can't find any documentation on `modernSCM()` so I don't know how to achieve this. Do I have to use `legacySCM()` instead? So many questions!

For now, the Library is 'hard coded' into the Jenkins global config, but this is sub-optimal for a few reasons.

Comment: That was it! I don't think my question is a duplicate, but that linked question had an example of the code I was able to cut&paste to fix my issue.